# Why am I getting different results while applying similarity and Pythagoras theorem?

Tags: geometry

[image]

AE=7.2 cm,AD=7.6 cm,BE=4.2 cm and BC=8.4 cm.

Now,find DE.

So,if we apply Pythagoras theorem in AED we have $ED=\sqrt {7.6^2-7.2^2}=2.433$.

But,if we apply similarity between AED and ACB, we have  $\frac {AD}{DE}=\frac {AB}{BC}$ and thus solving we get DE=5.6 cm.

So,why this inconsistency in results?

Comment: You should consider the possibility that the given figure is impossible.

Comment: so what do you want to calculate?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I want to calculate  $DE$...

Comment: @tatan Suppose you have $AE$, $EB$ and $BC$. From those values you can completely determine $AD$, but you'll get a different value than $7.6$. Hence your figure is impossible.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question that shows effort -- I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: @McFry  Your comment should be posted as an answer.

Comment: @mweiss how you say it is reasonable question?

Comment: Before doing problems if you check whether you write the correct question in your paper,you won't lead to such a misleading. Then how you say its reasonable @mweiss.

Comment: The OP is considering a question and has found, by two different methods, two different solutions.  He or she wants to know how to reconcile or otherwise account for those two contradictory results.  The resolution is that the initial figure is impossible -- but that is hardly self-evident (and in fact the OP's dilemma is itself a proof of that figure).  Seems like a very good question to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As McFry has said in the comments, the figure is impossible.  Suppose we try to construct it.  First, we construct right triangle $AED$ with the indicated measurements,and extend segment $AE$ so that $EB$ is $4.2$ units long, as shown:

[image]

Now to finish the construction we extend $AD$ and drop a perpendicular from $B$ to $AD$, as shown:

[image]

Note that the length of $BC$ is completely determined by the construction so far.  In fact, one can determine using similarity that $BC \approx 3.65$.  So there is no way to satisfy the conditions of the given diagram, which requires $BC = 8.4$.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw a circle with $AB$ as diameter on x axis, and midpoint of $AB$ as origin, let $A$ be negative and $B$ be positive, then $C$ will lie in first quadrant with given $AC$ length and in second quadrant with given $CB$ length. Since $C$ is a right angle, $C$ has to lie on the circle. Hence the construction is not possible.

Comment: Nice observation!!(+1)

Answer (score 0):

Your drawing is misleading, try making a figure to scale.

[image]